# How to fix Encoding error utf-8 - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, encoding

I am following instructions online to create a database in pgAdmin4. I have successfully imported a csv file and created a table. However, I cannot select anything from the table.

My code is:

`SELECT * FROM transfers;`

Error message is: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Running 'show server_encoding' gives "UTF8" in the output.
Running 'show client_encoding gives "UNICODE" in the output.

Comment: We are going to need more information. 1) The output of `show server_encoding ;` and `show clientencoding ;` 2) The source of the CSV file 3) The encoding of the CSV file. Add information as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for your reply. added the two outputs as requested. By source of the csv do yuo mean the filepath? it's a local file in my C drive. As for encoding of the csv file im not sure how to check that. Sorry I'm relatively new to coding

Comment: Since you mention `C` drive  you are Windows. What version? What is the locale? Where did the CSV file come from, in other words what produced it?

Comment: Also how did you import the CSV file into the database?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Windows 11, I downloaded the csv from kaggle and stored it in a folder. the import was successful (i made sure the column names in the table match those of the csv). I'm confident the import worked because the pop up says "successfully completed" and thwhen I write click on my table and chose "count rows", the correct number of rows appear.

Comment: "transfers" is the name of my table by the way

Comment: I imported by right clicking on the name of my table on the left hand side and choosing "import/export"

Comment: Best bet is that the CSV file is not in a Unicode/UTF8 encoding. You might try:  1) Deleting the records from the table. 2) Redo the import, but  this time in the encoding box select `ISO-8859-2`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ISO-8859-2 isn't available as an option for me.   ISO-8859-5 imports successfully but the same problem remains.  ISO-8859-8 doesn't let me import at all., I get "Failed (exit code: 1)"

Comment: Try `LATIN2` that is an alias for `ISO-8859-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you saved an excel file as csv and imported to postgre, if so, open excel, create a blank csv file and copy/paste your excel data to there and save. Delete your previous postgre table and import newly created csv file again.